# How to communicate between Java and Dart through Socket

Tags: java, sockets, dart

I would like to run a combination of Dart and Java code, that can communicate with each other. 
Therefore I chose to go with sockets, with the server socket written in Java and the client socket written in Dart.

This is the code I wrote:

#### Server

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
server.setSoTimeout(0);        
System.out.println("waiting for connection...");

while (true) {
    try {
        Socket client = socket.accept();
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("connected to " + client.getLocalSocketAddress() + ".");

        while (true) {
            output.write(input.readLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("disconnected.\n\nwaiting for connection...");
    }
}
```

#### Client

```
Socket client = await Socket.connect('localhost', 12345);
client.write('hello there\n');
client.close();
```

Unfortunately the server does not receive the ping message sent by the client. 
By now I suppose, that the problem lies in the Dart code, because when executing a client written in Java worked just fine.

Do you know, how to solve this? If so, please let me know ho. Thank you in advance!

---

#### Please note:

As there will never be more than one client at a time, I chose to go with this approach. I am aware, that normally this is no good style.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for `close()` on the Socket class:

> NOTE: Writes to the IOSink may be buffered, and may not be flushed by a call to close(). To flush all buffered writes, call flush() before calling close().

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/Socket/close.html

Comment: Hi julemand, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that did not help. I tested communicating between two Java programs and between two Dart programs - both worked. It seems to be any compatibility issue.

Comment: Did you await the flush?

Comment: Yes I did. But it did not change. I found out how to solve the problem and left an answer regarding that. But thank you for your effort anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but it seems that the problem lies in the `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`.

Here is what worked:

#### Server

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
server.setSoTimeout(0);        
System.out.println("waiting for connection...");

while (true) {
    try {
        Socket client = socket.accept();
        BufferedWriter output = BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("connected to " + client.getLocalSocketAddress() + ".");

        while (true) {
            output.writeUTF(input.readUTF());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("disconnected.\n\nwaiting for connection...");
    }
}
```

#### Client

```
Socket client = await Socket.connect('localhost', 12345);
client.write('hello there\n');
client.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
Socket client = socket.accept();
byte[] b = new byte[100];
client.getInputStream().read(b);
System.out.println(new String(b));
```